# Pinch to Resize, Drag to Move the Image control - Implementation WP 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

My code for moving the image control is:

```
<Grid Name="grid" Width="400" Height="400" ManipulationMode="All"  
  ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta_1" Margin="0,58,0,182">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform x:Name="transform" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <Image x:Name="Image1" Source="Assets/SmallLogo.png"  Stretch="None" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
</Grid>
```

Manipulation delta has code:

```
private void Grid_ManipulationDelta_1(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PointerDeviceType == PointerDeviceType.Touch)
    {
        this.transform.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        this.transform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        OutText.Text = sender.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This works perfect when I move image wherever on my grid.

Now for resizing the image control I have different implementation,

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrl2" SizeChanged="scrl_SizeChanged"  ZoomMode="Enabled" 
  HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" 
  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
  MinZoomFactor="0.1" MaxZoomFactor="10" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <Image Source="Assets/SmallLogo.png" Stretch="None" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
</ScrollViewer>
```

The scroll viewer can be resized here and image is child so it also can. And it changes size on runtime perfectly, but note that this is different code.

I want to implement both scenarios on image control, which seems logical, so I edit my xaml like this:

```
<Grid Name="grid" Width="400" Height="400" ManipulationMode="All"
  ManipulationStarted="Grid_ManipulationStarted_1"
  ManipulationCompleted="Grid_ManipulationCompleted_1"
  ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta_1" Margin="0,58,0,182">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform x:Name="transform" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>

    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrl2" SizeChanged="scrl_SizeChanged"
      ZoomMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" 
      VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  
      MinZoomFactor="0.1" MaxZoomFactor="10" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Image x:Name="Image1" Source="Assets/SmallLogo.png"  Stretch="None" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The `RenderTransform` should take care of movement and `ScrollViewer` should do pinch thing. But that does not work. In separate code when image is in scroll viewer only - pinch to zoom works, when image is in grid - drag to move works.

In the above code where I put image in `ScrollViewer` and that `ScrollViewer` in grid, only pinch to zoom works, movement does not work. I tried to undo the Horizontal Vertical alignment settings (set them to something null) but that is not possible. The image resizes, but remains always in the position it is set in alignment settings.

What is wrong in this implementation?